# uname -m does not give correct answer

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I have installed a fresh 32bit Raspberry Pi OS on my Raspi4 and the dotnet script is installing the wrong version. Inside the script, the command uname is used to determine the correct version:

$ uname -m

aarch64

but on the same device:

$ getconf LONG_BIT

32

Someone else has seen this?

Comment: That is all the intended outcome now https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=349291#p2093374

Comment: `uname` reports about the kernel, not the OS userland.  A 32-bit userland can be run by a 64-bit kernel and that's the norm for RpiOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to collect the comments so as to provide a "proper" answer to your question:

1. This was discussed extensively in the [RPi forum](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=349291&sid=2c65367b235ee9ff4e23de354f1237c7) back in March of 2023. You can read all the details there if you like, but this one comment sums it up:

> It is intended behaviour. It breaks very little. Mostly if you build your own modules. If you still need the 32-bit kernel you can put arm_64bit=0 in /boot/config.txt and reboot.

2. `uname` & its options are a little ambiguous (to my way of thinking). Per `man uname`, `uname -m` should give "the machine hardware name", but instead we get something suggestive of the processor architecture (`aarch64`). But not to worry; this means that the kernel is 64-bit, while the remainder of the system is 32-bit.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things. Now we just need to inform people that use uname to determine the OS version.

Comment: @drp: I think your question. helped do just that. :)

Answer (score 1):

"I have … a … 32bit Raspberry Pi OS" so why are you surprised that it is 32 bit!

If you want 64 bit install a 64 bit OS.